# How to limit the multi selection in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here are tableView data source and delegate implementation, and I set the maximum selection is 5.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    if ([multiOptions count] > 5) {
        [self tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selected = NO;
        //show alert
    }
    ...
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    [multiOptions removeObject:selectedOption];
    ...
}
```

but here comes a question, if the options exceed the limit, the first click on cell will work just fine. but second time click the cell will call

```
didDeselectRowAtIndexPath
```

again, that's not what i expected, and I tried

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, it didn't work, can someone give me a hint, how to correct it? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to check this in `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Have a look at the [UITableView class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3awillSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a)
especially at the last sentence:

> Return Value An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected
>   row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want
>   another cell to be selected. Return nil if you don't want the row
>   selected.

So something like this will work within `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
if ([multiOptions count] > 5) return nil;
```